# At what point do we say that the dependent variable cant be derived using the independent variables

Tags: machine-learning

I have some traffic data and a field that i feel should be derived/dependent on it. Both are time-series data but when I fit the models to predict the Y variable the coefficients are really small. Steps i took:

1. Scaled the variables using min-max scaler and removed outliers
2. checked the correlation between dependent and independent.
3. removed the seasonality
4. took the trend and residual
5. applied linear regression to predict y
6. results gives very low coefficients and R-square

Also if someone can share how they assert if the data is not enough to predict the Y how do you know?

Raw data looks like:
[image]
Model output:
[image]

Is there a way to attach data in here.

Comment: Please provide more details including a dscription of your variables, and model formulae and the output of the model(s). Removing outliers is usually a very bad idea unless you know with some level of certainty that they are the result of error or mistake. Otherwise they are just extreme values that should be retained.  Also min-max scaling will have no impact on a linear regression model.

Comment: yeah i removed the outliers only from y variable which I am pretty sure about. The data is captured at every 5 minute interval.

Comment: Can you also include plots of the data ?